# Is the position wavefunction a fundamental property of quantum object or is it an emergent property of the combination of more fundamental properties?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I've often seen a position wavefunction described in online resources explaining wavefunctions in quantum mechanics.

But I'm curious as to whether this wavefunction is fundamental to a quantum particle or derived from combining the wavefunctions associated with the fundamental forces? Or maybe whether it's actually somewhat contrived for demonstration purposes only?

My rationalisation is that a photons motion is described by the propagation of wave fronts in EM field (if we ignore space-time curvature for a second) and so the evolution of the position of a photon is really an emergent property of EM.

I imagine more complex particles like electrons have more complex wavefunctions that emerge from combinations of other wavefunctions relating to their various quantum properties.

I'm not a QM student or anything as is probably clear, just a huge physics enthusiast trying to get my head around QM, so appologies if I've missed the mark entirely.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but likely Bell's theorem rules out the idea that "the propagation of wave fronts in EM field ... and so the evolution of the position of a photon is really an emergent property of EM", since this seems like a local hidden variable theory.  That said, there is a (rather large) school of thought that the QM wave function is not a property of a *system* but rather a representation of an *agent's* knowledge *about* that system.  This is the epistemic view. It is rather common, if not a plurality, and stands at counterpoint to interpretations like Many Worlds, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The standard frame of quantum theories are:

Large quantum systems behave classically and can be desribed as individual objects like a golf ball, an experimenter with a hammer, setting up an experiment, where position and momentum are prepared and the time evolution in an external field yields obserable quantities, that can be retrived from position an momentum at a later time.

Since this scenario is not applicable for a single quantum particle, where position is not observable, one reverses the method and declares the momentum for the primary variable, because for free particles it is conserved and in collisions at least the sum is conserved.

The next quantum observable, conserved for free particles and absolutely conserved as sums in collisions is the angular momentum.

Finally, one isolates from classical relativistic mechanics the energy-momentum as the 4-vector and the angular momentum and their boost equvalents,  that are transforming under translations, rotations and Lorentz transformations as the primary observable algebra in collsions of free particles.

Analogously to the step of Huyghens collision dynamics to Newtons detailed time evolution dynamics in external fields, the free momentum algebra is deformed into an electrodynamics of charges particles by the intoduction of position dependent fields. the classical electrodymics of Newton/Maxell/Lorentz with its free one particle Hamiltonian in external fields.

$$  \frac{E^2}{c^2} = P^2 + m^2 c^2 \to  \frac{(E-e \Phi(x))^2}{c^2} = \left(P-\frac{e}{c} A(x)\right)^2 + m^2 c^2  $$

In order to represent free quantum electrodynamics, a position operator is without any relevance, because the fundamental difference betweeen classical and quantum mechanics is the following.

In classical mechanics the tiny observer has  fixed position in a universe observing events without interaction.

In quantum theory, the tiny object of obsrvation has a fixed position inside an isolated laboratory, pretending to be the empty universe, observer looking from outside with minimal interaction.

So the trivial representation of the momentum and rotation observables by free waves in irreducible representations of the Poincaré group, known to radio wave specialists since Maxwell, had to be adapted to Plancks trick to reduce the uncountable big space of waves with any real values of phases, wavelengths and polarisation amplitudes to a countable subspace by the requirement, that the wave space is a Hilbert space. In a big box, this reduces all wavenumbers to integer multiples. This countability made statistics sound and, by the way introduced the concept of orthogonal modes with fixed amplitude  and freuency, that can be regarded is particles themselves, aka photons.

Back to the position operator in quantum theories: The representaion of the fundamental momentum algebra in Hilbert spaces of time dependent waves in 3-space introduces a new position operator by the operation $X : f(x)\to x f(x)$.

Normally, the result is not in the Hilbert space, but on a subspace of functions falling off fast at infinity, its a linear map.  Its now straight forward, to show, that the classical momentum $P$ and the electromagnetic potentials $\Phi(x), A(x)$, transferred to quantum physics  as

$$E-\Phi(x),P-e A(x)  \to -i \partial_x \psi(x) -e A(X) \psi(x)$$
yield a working time evalution model in Hilbert space for any start configation $\psi(t=0,x)$ in Hilbert space by the unitary group generated by the Hamilton operator $H(P,X)$.

This concept worked for the H-Atom astonshingly exact, yielding the spectrum and the radiation and collision data.

All these concepts are unified in the axiomatic approaches (Wightman axioms for fields, Haag/Ruelle for operator algebras of observables, Osterwalder/Schrader for stochastic processes called euclidean quantum field theory), that defines an algebra of observables based on $X,P$ in a space-time area in Minkowski space and Hilbert spaces on spatial subspaces and seeks irreducible representations of any typey of groups, that are observed as categories of free fundamental particles.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied yet. I've been trying to find time to understand this properly. Some of this is definitely currently over my head